# PPT VBA auto-select new textbox?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a macro to create a new textbox with certain parameters, but when it is created, I still have to go click it (and then use "Enter" as a keyboard shortcut to highlight the text and start typing). 
I was wondering if there's a way to have the textbox selected as soon as I run the macro, and even better, if there's a way to auto-highlight the test text (so that there is no step between adding the box and typing).

Code below (copied & slightly modified from [The Spreadsheet Guru](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/2/22/create-a-shape-or-text-box-and-format-it)).

```
Dim Sld As Slide
Dim Shp As Shape

'ERROR HANDLING
If ActivePresentation.Slides.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "You do not have any slides in your PowerPoint project."
    Exit Sub
End If

Set Sld = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

'Create shape with Specified Dimensions and Slide Position
Set Shp = Sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal,      Left:=24, Top:=65.6, Width:=300, Height:=100)

'FORMAT SHAPE
'No Shape Border
    Shp.Line.Visible = msoFalse

'Shape Fill Color
    Shp.Fill.Visible = msoFalse

'Shape Text Color
    Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)

'Text inside Shape
    Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Text"

'Center Align Text
    Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft

'Vertically Align Text to Middle
    Shp.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorTop

'Adjust Font Size
    Shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 12

'Adjust Font Style
    Shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Name = "Arial"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add this line at the end:

```
 Shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Select
```